# What's so special about the atmospheric continuum?

Tags: bewitched

In Bewitched, whenever Darrin asks Samantha to explain some magical thing, or any magical explanation for that matter, it always seems there's reference to something called 'the atmospheric continuum'.  Once that term is said, Darrin normally looks bewildered, tired and tells Samantha to stop.  But question: what *is* the atmospheric continuum and what's so special about it - what connection to magic does it have?  I know this is a sitcom, but still this seems to be rather major to the show and I haven't found any reference to its importance in-show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the magical equivalent of the term "[tech](http://www.blastr.com/2009/10/ron_moore_calls_star_trek.php)" in a Star Trek script. It's a placeholder piece of gobbledegook to explain that *something magical has happened but we (the laypeople) are simply too unmagical to understand it.*

One of the quotes is;

> "Darrin, don't inter this atrophy of action causes the undistributed
>   metaphysical particles to clutter up the atmospheric continuum,
>   thereby creating a bilateral transcendental trauma, or in layman's
>   terms, a vapor lock."

Which frankly is just gibberish.

Ron Moore, senior writer for Star Trek gives a pretty good description of this writing process;

> *"It became the solution to so many plot lines and so many stories," Moore said. "It was so mechanical that we had science consultants who
>   would just come up with the words for us and we'd just write 'tech' in
>   the script. You know, Picard would say 'Commander La Forge, tech the
>   tech to the warp drive.' I'm serious. If you look at those scripts,
>   you'll see that."

Out of universe, an [atmospheric continuum](http://www.eumetcal.org/euromet/english/nwp/n2200/n2200003.htm) is described as the *whole* atmosphere, including all the relevant forces (e.g. gravity, heat, pressure, etc) that can act upon it. My guess is that the writers literally had no idea about this meaning. They're simply using the term to mean [skywave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skywave).

Comment: I thought it would be mumbo-jumbo to make it look like they were saying something intelligent

Comment: They seem to alternate between using it to mean skywave and just using it meaninglessly

Comment: He finally asks a non-Star Trek question and yet **still** gets an answer dealing with Star Trek. I think I might explode with laughter at the absurdity of this. : D

Comment: @MeatTrademark - I couldn't resist myself. It seemed like an appropriate example and I'd just been reading the article...